# difference between List<Integer> arr and var arr

Tags: java, containers, sublist

The following code works fine.

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println(arr.getClass().getSimpleName()); // output: ArrayList
arr.add(0);
arr.add(1);
arr = arr.subList(0,1);
```

But if you change the first line to

```
var arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

an error will occur:

> java: incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>

However, even if arr is defined in the second way, its type is still ArrayList, so what is the difference?

Comment: What line is the error occuring?

Comment: there's a difference between what the runtime type is and what the compiler knows it is

Answer (score 8):

When you write

```
var arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

the compiler infers the type of the `arr` variable to be `ArrayList<Integer>`, so it's equivalent to writing:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

`arr.subList(0,1)` returns a `List<Integer>`, which cannot be assigned to an `ArrayList<Integer>`, since an `ArrayList<Integer>` is an implementation of `List<Integer>`, but not all implementations of `List<Integer>` are `ArrayList<Integer>`.

On the other hand, when you declare the variable as `List<Integer> arr`, you can assign to it any implementation of `List<Integer>`, which includes the value returned by `arr.subList(0,1)`.

It's important to note that `subList` does **not** return an `ArrayList`.
For example, `subList()` method of `ArrayList` returns an instance of an inner class called `ArrayList$SubList`. Such `List` cannot be assigned to a variable whose type is `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guessed it was a type error, so I used System.out.println(arr.getClass().getSimpleName()); to print the type, but found that the two methods give same output "ArrayList" .  how can I know that the variable defined using the first method is not of the same type as the second?

Comment: @Acuzio: you can't get the compile-time type of a local variable at runtime, that information is simply not accessible at runtime. Only the run-time type of the actual object referenced is accessible. The best way to find out what type a `var` actually "resolves to" is to have an IDE which will give you that information (IntelliJ IDEA does that on hover, but I guess most/all modern IDEs can do that).

Comment: @Acuzio there's a difference between the compile time type of a variable and the runtime type of the instance referenced by that variable. Even if the runtime type is `ArrayList` is both cases (before you assign the list returned by `subList`), the compile time type is not.